# PHP storing password with blowfish & salt & pepper

Tags: php, hash, salt, blowfish, crypt

I want to store secure user passwords in a MySQL database with PHP.

How can I make it better?

My Class:

```php
private static $algo = '$2a';
private static $cost = '$10';
private static $pepper = 'eMI8MHpEByw/M4c9o7sN3d';

public static function generateSalt($length) {
    $randomBinaryString = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $randomEncodedString = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($randomBinaryString));
    return substr($randomEncodedString, 0, $length);
}

public static function generateHash($password) {
    if (!defined('CRYPT_BLOWFISH'))
        die('The CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm is required (PHP 5.3).');
    $password = hash_hmac('sha256', $password, self::$pepper, false);
    return crypt($password, self::$algo . self::$cost . '$' . self::generateSalt(22));
}

public static function checkPassword($hash, $password) {
    $salt = substr($hash, 0, 29);
    $password = hash_hmac('sha256', $password, self::$pepper, false);
    $new_hash = crypt($password, $salt);
    return ($hash == $new_hash);
}
```

Comment: While this technically has an answer, your question is fairly arbitrary and open-ended and should be reworded to address a specific problem instead.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first "question", next time I will make it better!

Comment: No problem; I gave a broad answer with some tips on hashing and security in general.

Comment: Have a look at the use of the new PHP functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14274045/575765).

Comment: Shouldn't this be in Code Review SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14274045/575765) answer's suggestions (for PHP >= 5.5), or the following class. Thanks to [martinstoeckli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575765/martinstoeckli) for pointing out the `password_hash` functions. I read the code over, and the only different thing in `password_hash` that I can see is error-checking and `DEV_URANDOM` usage from the OS to generate a more random salt.

```
class PassHash {
    public static function rand_str($length) {
        $chars = "0123456789./qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
        //only allowed chars in the blowfish salt.
        $size = strlen($chars);
        $str = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
            $str .= $chars[rand(0, $size - 1)]; // hello zend and C.
        return $str;
    }
    public static function hash($input) {
        return crypt($input, "$2y$13$" . self::rand_str(22));
        // 2y is an exploit fix, and an improvement over 2a. Only available in 5.4.0+
    }
    public static function hash_weak($input) {
        return crypt($input, "$2a$13$" . self::rand_str(22)); }
        // legacy support, Add exception handling and fall back to <= 5.3.0
    public static function compare($input, $hash) {
        return (crypt($input, $hash) === $hash);
    }
}
```

It's what I've always used. A suggestion is also [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). It's tried and tested.

---

The only downfall in this script is that I generate random numbers from `rand()`, and not the source from the OS, but that's easily changed.

Also, there is no real reason to be using `SHA256` hashing on top of bcrypt. `SHA256` is weak, and can be broken with relatively little effort<sup>3</sup>.

In addition, hashing passwords is essential practice, but for true security, **run all input through at least [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/)'s [wordlist](http://www.openwall.com/wordlists/)<sup>1</sup>** to remove the most common passwords and inform a user to use a different password. Wordlists are used far more effectively than any bruteforce due to terribly weak passwords.

---

And as a final note, ***do not force your users to use symbols, uppercase and numbers, force them to use a long password***<sup>2</sup>.

Length is everything (no humour intended) when it comes to bruteforcing passwords. Pretty much any preset cracker will be set to not go over 12 characters unless a config is edited. If you ever see a site with a "maximum length" on passwords, make sure to never re-use a password there, because they have no security whatsoever<sup>4</sup>.

---

<sup>1. Arbitrary choice of cracker; pick what you find to work best

2. http://xkcd.com/936/

3. Comparatively (it's several orders of magnitude faster and is technically security through obscurity)

4. I have even seen banks do this. Having a maximum length on their passwords made me switch banks.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for the good hints, I will consider this.

Comment: @FillipPeyton bcrypt hashes store the salt with them. Just pass the input to `::Compare()`, it works fine in the five sites I have that use this ([example here](https://github.com/HirotoKun/admin-panel/blob/master/admin/private.php#L93)) - asking for salt, pepper, hash and options all separately is something I haven't done.... ever.

Comment: @FillipPeyton the hash and the salt are in the same string. it's in the form `$<cipher>$<cost>$<salt><hash>`. Store it and compare; it is quite literally as easy as `PassHash::Compare($password_input, $hash_from_database); //true if correct else false`. You are waaay overthinking this.