# PHP Compare a crypted password from db with an inserted password from a form

Tags: php, hash, cryptography, passwords, md5

I've a db with crypted password. When a user logs in, i make this:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,$query));
$cryptedPass = $result['password'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
if(strcmp($cryptedPass,md5($pass))==0)
   echo "yeah!";
```

It works, but I would like to know if this the right manner, or if there is something of safer!

Comment: You should go to the "Code Review" network. They will be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: I would look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003988/php-storing-password-with-blowfish-salt-pepper

Comment: Did you meant `md5`? And no, don't use `md5()`. Specially without a salt.

Comment: You are right guys, I've missclicked 'd'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use MD5. There are plenty of online documents that explain how insecure this is. For example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

I would recommend using the `crypt()` function.

Read here: http://php.net/crypt

A good one to use would be `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`

Here's a function I found a while back, that I use. Unfortunately I can't remember where I found it, so I can't reference the author.

```
function blowfishEncrypt($string,$rounds) {
        $salt = "";
        $saltCharacters = array_merge(range('A','Z'),range('a','z'),range(0,9));
        for ($i=0;$i<22;$i++) {
            $salt .= $saltCharacters[array_rand($saltCharacters)];
        }
        $hashstring = crypt($string,'$2y$' . $rounds . '$' . $salt);

        return $hashstring;
    }
```

To create the encrypted password, you would use it like so:

```
$cryptedPass=blowfishEncrypt($clearPass,'07');
```

Then to compare, you would use:

```
if($cryptedPass==crypt($pass,$cryptedPass)) {
    echo 'Yeah!';
}
```

Note: If you are using a version of PHP before 5.3.7, the salt prefix must be `$2a$`.

> PHP 5.3.7 introduced the new prefix `$2y$` to fix a security weakness
>   in the Blowfish implementation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80943/discussion-on-answer-by-stretch-php-compare-a-crypted-password-from-db-with-an-i).